# Does TODO work in NetBeans for C++?

Tags: c++, netbeans, todo

I hope this isn't a tedious question as it has a lot of variations here, but none of the existing questions seem to quite fit my scenario. Google hasn't saved me yet either.

I'm using netbeans to develop a C++ project. The Action Items window is supposed to show me a list of the places where I've put TODO or @todo in the comments, but it's blank. I've made certain that I'm using a filter that includes TODO and I've double checked the ToDo Patterns list in Options->Misc->ActionItems to make sure that I'm entering the correct syntax.

UPDATE:
Now I feel silly. Just after posting my question I found the answer. I'll post it for other's with the same issue:

Somewhere in this bug ticket, https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=184292, someone says, 
"btw, you can turn tasks support as:
- Tools->Options->C/C++->Project Options and check
-- 'Support indexing of not C/C++/Fortran files (slow down parsing)'"

That's mostly accurate. I found the option under Tools->Options->C/C++->**Other**
After checking that it took a restart and a couple seconds and my TODO items came right up.

Comment: I had the same issue and having to use options to work around a bug is anything but intuitive. FWIW, still not fixed 12 months later in 7.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Go to Tools->Options->C/C++->Other

2.) Check 'Support indexing of not C/C++/Fortran files (slow down parsing)'

3.) Restart NetBeans

Note, using this solution really does slow down the other automatic functions, or at least it has for me.